# I have created an html generating js function based on JSON. Is this more effective than templating engines or doing it manually by code?

Tags: html, json, template-engine

Could you please check if this function is more effective from a coding point of view than templating engines or manually creating the html elements through code?

https://github.com/krishnakumar-m/simple-html-templating-json

I have checked github for use of JSON to generate HTML. But was not able to find any. I found this a bit more handy while dynamically generating html elements, because I was able to visualize the HTML as JSON.

Why are we not using JSON for structuring HTML this way? Is there a catch here? Or are there libraries which does the same thing?

Comment: The search-term "generate html from json github" generates 8.4 million hits in google. The first page (10 results) are all found at the github domain. :) So yes, it appears that there are _many_ libraries which do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @enhzflep, I have seen those. But thought my json format is simple and easy to understand and visualize than the ones in the market. The function size is also very low.